# Select rows where two columns cannot be 0 at same time

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table full of songs. Every row has column minutes and column seconds. What I want to do is create query for selecting all songs that don't have both columns set to zero(minutes = 0 && seconds = 0). But at the same time I want to collect all songs that have 0 minutes and x seconds || x minutes and 0 seconds.

Comment: `where  minutes <> 0 or seconds <> 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward

```
SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE NOT(minutes = 0 AND seconds = 0)
```

There are couple more solutions @GordonLinoff suggested one also:

```
SELECT * FROM Songs WHERE minutes <> 0 OR seconds = 0
```